# Adding really small values in java

Tags: java

I'm am currently working on a program in java which requires adding a small constant value such as 0.00000000001 to a double variable, ex. location. However, when I run the code, debug it, and get to the place where I add  0.00000000001 to location, and check the  value of location in debug mode after the addition takes place. It appears that location doesn't have 0.00000000001 added to it. For example, location will equal 438.0 before the addition and 438.0 after the addition. Here is a example of what the simple code looks like

location += 0.00000000001

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many double values are not exactly precise in Java due to the way it is stored. Exact precision only applies for certain values. This is because Java can only store a decimal value as a combination of many 2^n (s).

Eg: `1/4` can be stored as `2^-2`, but `1/3` will be stored as `2^-2 + 2^-3+ 2^-4 +2^-5...`, so `1/3` is an example of a value that is not exactly precise

If you want a precise value, use the `BigDecimal` class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: They *are* precise, but they don't have arbitrary precision, nor can they represent every decimal number exactly. The double value for 0.5 is still exactly 0.5.

Comment: Yes i understand that. Edited.

Comment: So just to clarify. doubles can hold really large numbers with decimals, they just have trouble handling decimals when they become extremely small?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for better precision.

Example:

```
BigDecimal test = new BigDecimal(438.0);
test = test.add(new BigDecimal(0.0000000000001));
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: So just to clarify. doubles can hold really large numbers with decimals, they just have trouble handling decimals when they become extremely small?

Comment: Yes. It is because of the way they are represented - as `2^n`.

Comment: Ok. I have a computer science background so I think I understand what you are trying to say. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use the BigDecimal class. It has arbitrary precision, and will be able to handle tiny values.

Answer (score 2):

If you exceed the precision of `double` adding a very small value does nothing.

```
for (double d = 438; d < 1e7; d *= 10) {
    double location = d;
    location += 0.00000000001;
    System.out.println(location);
}
```

prints

```
438.00000000001
4380.00000000001
43800.00000000001
438000.0
4380000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running into a rounding error or underflow. I'd try using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

you should read though http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/java_double_traps.html

This gets into how java stores and handles doubles and floats and what they mean when you use and compare them.

This is basically a case of "WHAT YOU SEE IS NOT WHAT YOU GET"

and if you decide to use big decimal this has its own cases of traps

http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/java/traps/big_decimal_traps.html

This really comes down to what are you trying to do with adding 0.00000000001 ??

Comment: II just need to make the difference of two values as little as possible when they are originally equal, without making them equal to prevent from dividing by zero in some cases in my algorithm. This is just a quick fix for now that I hope to fix later, but haven't been able to find a proper solution to yet.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to add to another answers. The problem is not with too small values. Bigger value = bigger infelicity. See an example:

```
 float x = 20000000.0f;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
     x += 1;
 }
 System.out.println(x); // prints 20000000.0f, not 30000000.0f!
```

So if you use floating numbers in loops you can never exit this loop