# Finite Machine with Double values in Java

Tags: java, double

I am trying to find out why I get result 0.0?

This my code:

```
public void rechneFunktion() {

    double x1 = Math.pow(10, 20);
    double x2 = 1223.0;
    double x3 = Math.pow(10, 18);
    double x4 = Math.pow(10, 15);
    double x5 = 3.0;
    double x6 = Math.pow(10, 12) * (-1);

    double y1 = Math.pow(10, 20);
    double y2 = 2.0;
    double y3 = Math.pow(10, 22) * (-1);
    double y4 = Math.pow(10, 13);
    double y5 = 2111.0;
    double y6 = Math.pow(10, 16);

    double erg = (x1 * y1) +(x3 * y3)+ (x2 * y2) + (x4 * y4)+(x5 * y5)+(x6 * y6);
    System.out.println(erg);
}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?  What are the intermediate values?

Comment: when i print   erg i should get 8779 but i get 0.0

Comment: Ok, well have you checked the intermediate results to see which one's wrong?

Comment: ([wolfram alpha link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E20*10%5E20%2B1223*2%2B10%5E18*-1*10%5E22%2B10%5E15*10%5E13%2B2111*3%2B-1*10%5E12*10%5E16))

Comment: It feels you have **overflow issue** but when I ran debugging mood,I did not see it

Comment: when i remove   (x3 * y3) i get 1.0E40

Comment: no last setpes gives you this 1.0E16

Comment: my Professor say it should work with double and the result is 8779. but i must change somthing to get the correct result. i tried to cast but it didnt help

Comment: Sounds like a rounding issue to me, (1E40 >> 2*1223)

Comment: @KickButtowski floating points (`float` and `double`) don't overflow like that.

Comment: @yshavit how do they do overflow? can you tel me plz?

Comment: @user3232446 +1 for your good and interesting question

Comment: @KickButtowski It's in [JLS 4.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4). Basically, numbers that are too big or too small ("overflow") become positive or negative infinity, and numbers that are too close to 0 ("underflow") become positive or negative 0. But they never wrap around, like ints do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the values that cancel each other out. Try using the following:

```
double erg = ((x1 * y1) + (x3 * y3)) + 
             ((x2 * y2) +(x5 * y5))  + 
             ((x4 * y4) + (x6 * y6));
```

Comment: its work!!  many thanks! can you may be explain me why should do like this?

Comment: aha i understand now.  its look like this : 0+8779 +0

Comment: @RizJa please can you explain your sloution so I can vote you up

Comment: @user3232446 can you post up your answer with explantion please

Comment: rgettman has the answer spot on! It's due to how Java handles precision - it's precise only in certain cases. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017367/adding-really-small-values-in-java . The accepted answer is succinct and does a great job at explaining.

Answer (score 5):

The `double` values you are using only have about 17-18 digits of precision (53 bits).  Because of this, when you add the small values and the large values, the large value is not affected.  Then the large values are subtracted out, leaving `0`.

Mathematically, you are calculating the expression:

10<sup>20</sup> x 10<sup>20</sup> + 10<sup>18</sup> x (-10<sup>22</sup>) + 1,223 x 2 + 10<sup>15</sup> x 10<sup>13</sup> + 3 x 2,111 + (-10<sup>22</sup>) * 10<sup>16</sup>

Simplifying:

10<sup>40</sup> - 10<sup>40</sup> + 2,446 + 10<sup>28</sup> + 6,333 - 10<sup>28</sup>

Mathematically, the 10<sup>40</sup> and -10<sup>40</sup> cancel, and so do the 10<sup>28</sup> and -10<sup>28</sup>, leaving 8,779.

Because of the limited precision of `double`s, the "small" values get wiped out.  Here's what happens at each step of the summation in Java:

1. 10<sup>40</sup> => `1.0E40`
2. - 10<sup>40</sup> => `0.0`
3. + 2,446 => `2446.0`
4. + 10<sup>28</sup> => `1.0E28`  The `2446` gets wiped out because of precision issues.
5. + 6,333 => `1.0E28` The `6333` gets wiped out because of precision issues.
6. -10<sup>28</sup> => `0.0`

To get the proper value of `8779.0`, do the cancellations first, not adding the "small" values when the sum is currently too large for them to fit in the precision.

```
double erg = (x1 * y1) +(x3 * y3)+ (x4 * y4) + (x6 * y6) + (x2 * y2) +(x5 * y5);
```